# Strange behavior when sudo -u

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, sudo

I'm trying to set up daily backups of my postgres database. To that end I've created a /home/backups directory, and inside it the /home/backups/postgres directory. The owner of `/home/backups/postgres` is `postgres`, that is also the group of the directory.

Now I try to run `pg_dumpall > /home/backups/postgres/database.bak`.

When I run `sudo -u postgres pg_dumpall ...` I get a permission denied error. However, when I run `sudo su postgres` and then `pg_dumpall ...`, it works fine.

What is going on?

Comment: What's the permissions on pg_dumpall - and if you issue `which pg_dumpall` do you get the right one? Because that would be my guess.

Comment: Both return /usr/bin/pg_dumpall, which is a link to another file, owned by root with r-x permissions for group and other.

Comment: Ah, yeah. You're trying to write to `database.bak` as you, rather than the `postgres` user. The `permission denied` isn't running the command, it's redirecting the output.

Comment: Yeah, that's basically it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run:

```
sudo -u postgres pg_dumpall > /home/backups/postgres/database.bak
```

Then `pg_dumpall` is running as that user. But the redirect is still running as you. That's probably where your `permission denied` comes from, rather that the command. If you redirect to `/tmp/dump.out` does that work?

Otherwise you might need to do

```
sudo -u postgres bash -c "pg_dumpall > /home/backups/postgres/database.bak"
```

Comment: Cool! Now I'm sure my crontab job will run properly.